# Building blocks of Life

Tags: beginner, clojure, game-of-life

I'm learning Clojure, and decided to write a Conway's Game of Life clone as my starting project. I ended up dicking around for a bit before diving in, and came up with a few functions that I'd like looked over. Mainly, I'm concerned about writing them more concisely and idiomatically.

---

I'm planning on using a 1D vector to represent a 2D field. The typical equation to get the index of a vector corresponding to an (x,y) coordinate is y * width + x. Here are my first attempts:

```
; A 2D point representing a coordinate, or any pair of numbers
(defrecord Point [x y])

; Represents the Game of Life world.
; cells is a vector representing a 2D matrix of cells
; dims is the dimensions of the world as a Point
(defrecord Enviro [cells dims])

(defn index-of [width x y]
  (+ (* y width) x))

(defn enviro-index-of [enviro x y]
  (let [width (:x (:dims enviro))]
    (index-of width x y)))

(defn enviro-index-of-2 [enviro x y]
  (let [width (-> enviro :dims :x)]
    (index-of width x y)))
```

`index-of` is straight forward. My issue is the 2 convenience functions to get an index by supplying the Enviro instead of the width directly. I tried deconstructing the record directly in the argument list, but it complained that it didn't recognize the keyword record keys. The work-around was to just "navigate" the records manually, and bind "width" in a `let`. My first attempt was kind of naïve; using the accessor functions to get the `Enviro`, then the dimensions `Point`. Then I remembered the thread macro! For my second attempt, I used `->` to find the width. It seems to be much cleaner, but is this as idiomatic as it gets?

---

Next, I decided to try writing a function that returns a vector containing all the points surrounding a given point. I can then check the cell at each neighboring point to see whether or not the center point should be dead or alive:

```
(defn generate-neighbor-points
  ([cx cy r]
   (let [start-x (- cx r)
         end-x (+ cx r 1) ; Adding 1 so it's inclusive
         start-y (- cy r)
         end-y (+ cy r 1)]
     (for [y (range start-y end-y)
           x (range start-x end-x)
           :when (and (not= x cx) (not= y cy))] ; Should actually be `or` instead of `and`
       (Point. x y))))

  ([center-point r]
   (let [cx (:x center-point)
         cy (:y center-point)]
     (generate-neighbor-points cx cy r))))
```

There's a couple things that I'm not happy about here:

1. The fact that this generates a list of cells, just so it can be checked. I might see if I can just make this a higher-order function that takes a callback that's executed on each Point surrounding the cell. That might be thinking too javascript-y though.
2. The fact that this requires the creation of 2 "range"s, which are really full lists. This seems to be the best way of "iterating" a range of numbers and returning a list. I'm open for suggestions on how to make this more efficient and idiomatic though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot that you can streamline here. For your `Point` record:

```
; A 2D point representing a coordinate, or any pair of numbers
(defrecord Point [x y])
```

If you were only going to use a `Point` to represent a 2D Cartesian coordinate pair, this record *may* have some value, but not very much. The problem is the "or any pair of numbers" part. If you want to represent a pair of numbers in Clojure, just use a vector:

```
[4 2]
```

Vectors are very easy to destructure:

```
(defn prettify [point]
  (let [[x y] point]
    (str "(" x ", " y ")")))

(prettify [4 2])
;=> "(4, 2)"
```

Or if you want to just get the `first` or `second` element in a pair, you can do that as well:

```
(first [4 2])
;=> 4

(second [4 2])
;=> 2
```

You're creating a fair bit of extra work (e.g. the `index-of` functions) for yourself by representing your 2D world as a 1D vector. Using a 2D vector instead would eliminate the need for all three of those functions, as well as the `Enviro` record itself:

```
(def enviro (vec (repeatedly 10 (fn [] (vec (repeatedly 10 (fn [] (rand-int 10))))))))

(pprint enviro)
;; [[3 7 6 2 9 8 5 7 0 2]
;;  [0 6 4 7 1 7 0 7 1 9]
;;  [1 8 0 5 6 9 7 7 8 3]
;;  [7 9 0 8 4 3 3 7 8 6]
;;  [8 9 3 5 1 4 6 5 0 2]
;;  [6 2 3 2 9 4 8 0 3 1]
;;  [0 5 7 7 7 9 0 0 9 5]
;;  [3 8 9 8 2 0 6 3 1 9]
;;  [9 7 4 1 5 8 0 5 1 2]
;;  [9 9 1 9 4 6 3 1 8 2]]
;=> nil

(get-in enviro [4 2])
;=> 3
```

Or, if your matrix is sparse, you could use a map from points to values instead:

```
(def enviro (into {} (repeatedly 10 (fn [] [[(rand-int 10) (rand-int 10)] (rand-int 10)]))))

(pprint enviro)
;; {[2 8] 7,
;;  [5 4] 2,
;;  [4 2] 6,
;;  [7 8] 1,
;;  [9 6] 5,
;;  [1 7] 2,
;;  [2 6] 3,
;;  [6 0] 5,
;;  [3 5] 4,
;;  [0 1] 5}
;=> nil

(get enviro [4 2])
;=> 6
```

If you just use a plain hash map for this, you'll lose some of the spatial query capabilities of a vector, but you could get some of those back by using a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or some other spatially indexed data structure. I'll leave it up to you to decide how to go about doing that in Clojure if you want to take that route.

Your `generate-neighbor-points` function looks pretty good. Since `range` and `for` return lazy sequences, your implementation doesn't have any real performance issues. If I were to write it myself, though, I would probably be a bit more terse:

```
(defn neighbors [point radius]
  (let [[xs ys] (map #(range (- % radius) (+ % radius 1)) point)]
    (for [y ys x xs :when (not= point [x y])]
      [x y])))
```

There's nothing wrong with just returning the sequence of neighbor points and then leaving it up to the caller to decide what to do with them. I wouldn't recommend complecting the "find all the neighbor points" logic and the "do something with each of those neighbor points" logic into the same function, because I think it would make more sense to put that second bit in a separate function:

```
(defn update-all [enviro points f]
  (reduce #(update-in %1 %2 f) enviro points))
```

Example (using the 2D vector `enviro` example above):

```
(pprint (update-all enviro (neighbors [4 3] 2) #(mod % 2)))
;; [[3 7 6 2 9 8 5 7 0 2]
;;  [0 6 4 7 1 7 0 7 1 9]
;;  [1 0 0 1 0 1 7 7 8 3]
;;  [7 1 0 0 0 1 3 7 8 6]
;;  [8 1 1 5 1 0 6 5 0 2]
;;  [6 0 1 0 1 0 8 0 3 1]
;;  [0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 9 5]
;;  [3 8 9 8 2 0 6 3 1 9]
;;  [9 7 4 1 5 8 0 5 1 2]
;;  [9 9 1 9 4 6 3 1 8 2]]
;=> nil
```

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot about this answer! Since then, I've started using vectors to act as a "tuple" as you suggested, which allows for a very neat destructuring syntax. The rest was very helpful too. Thank you.